# Next steps to solve this equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Two equations: $$3X = 2PY \tag{1}$$ and $$27X - XY - 12Y = 0\tag{2}$$ Need to substitute the first equation into the second and solve for: $$X$$

The correct answer is **$$X = 18P - 12\tag{3}$$**

From the first equation: $$Y = 1.5X/PY\tag{4}$$

Inserted into the second equation: $$27X - X (1.5X/PY) - 12(1.5X/PY) = 0\tag{5}$$

Expanded: $$27X - 1.5X^2/PY - 18X/PY = 0\tag{6}$$

**However, I keep getting stuck at this point. If I multiply through by PY to get rid of the denominator, would it be** $$27XPY - 1.5X^2 - 18X = 0?$$ I'm not sure whether the RHS should also be PY (but my logic was that PY multiplied by 0 is 0). Also, I'm not completely sure if my working so far is correct, so any help on the next steps would be appreciated to know if I'm on the right lines.

Thanks!

Comment: You made a mistake on line (4). It should be $Y = \frac{1.5X}{P}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly see that equation (4) is wrong.
It should be

$$Y=\frac{1.5X}{P}$$
Put it in equation (1) to get

$$27X-\frac{1.5 X^2}{P}-12\times\frac{1.5X}{P}=0$$

and now proceed

Comment: Ah, thank you! If I multiplied through by P and factorised, would I get $$X(27P - 1.5X - 18) = 0?$$

Comment: @MathsHelp Yep, that's what's coming. If u found the ans helpful, click tick ;)

Comment: Right, I'm not really sure how to solve for X when it's factorised - any suggestions?

Comment: @MathsHelp You multiply throughout by P, then take $X$ as common to get $X(27P-1.5X-18)=0$, now it's a form of $a\times b =0$ wither $a=0$ or $b=0$. Both will satisfy the equation, In your case, try $b=0$

Comment: Right, so you mean substitute P for 0? So that it's $$X(0 - 1.5X - 18) = 0?$$

Comment: @MathsHelp NO. NOT AT ALL. I am saying that over here, $b=(27P-1.5X-18)$ put it equal to $0$